# Retain form data while paging through a GridView - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview, paging

I have a GridView control on my ASP.NET page that binds to result set when the user executes a search.  I create an additional TemplateField column with a CheckBox control to allow the user to select a sub set of records from the result set.  I have implemented paging in the GridView control and when the user checks the checkbox control and pages through the result set it does not retain any of the checked checkboxes.

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="MyCheckBox" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Whaat is the best way to retain the checked checkboxes while paging through the GridView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to maintain the state yourself. This [Thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vswebdeveloperexpresspt/thread/2e787edd-aba7-452c-9eb3-3694872b8f9a) shows how this can be done in VB. just use this [VB to C# converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/) to get your desired code

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to loop over the rows and save the checked state of the check boxes (along with a datakey) during the gridview paging event. Likewise you will need to read from your saved check state list to re-check the boxes during the gridview rowdatabound event.